# How to solve this simple memory leak problem on Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a memory leak problem in my application in qt creator.

I have a class (A) which has, among its attributes, a pointer to type B objects.

Each of these class B pointers is initialized into a third class called C, which passes the pointer to class A, which adds it to its vector.

Class A has a `deleteBfromVector ()` method.
This method is called in C.cpp and has among its arguments the pointer to B to be eliminated.

C is a Qt designer form class,not a c++ class.

My question is: how do I delete (with 'delete') the pointer I want to remove from the class A vector, thus avoiding memory leaks?

Do I have to do it in class C?

Clearly, the classes thus described have been readjusted and simplified exclusively to ask you this question, focusing only on the problem in question.

I am writing the code below:

```
class A{
 public:
    void add_B_to_vector(B* b_to_add){
    B_pointers_vector.push_back(b_to_add);
   }
    void remove_B_to_vector(B* b_to_remove){
    B_pointers_vector.erase(b_to_remove);
    // Here I would like to make b_to_remove be deleted from memory,and not just removed from vector            
 }
 private:
//...
vector <B*> B_pointers_vector;

};

class B{
    // attributes and methods of B
};
```

Comment: `std::vector <std::unique_ptr<B>>`...

Comment: Use `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` if you can. Otherwise, if when removed from `A` it is always to be deleted, then make it `delete` in the remove method. But, if `C` is creating them, then it should normally be deleting them too. Needs a bit more info on the design, I think.

Comment: `Do I have to do it in class C?` the class owning those pointers is responsible to delete them, when the instance holding that pointer(s) is deleted. So If `C` passes ownership over to `A` then `A` should delete those when its instance is destructed. If the program is designed so that `C` keeps the ownership and only provided the pointer to `A` then `C` should delete those. And as this information is missing, it is not possible to tell who should do the delete.

Comment: use delete on the destructor to delete the pointers , also more code will be better to understand what u doing .

Comment: What does “initialized into … C” mean?  Why does C matter here at all?